# UIPicker won't set text field

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipicker

I have a custom Picker with country list and corresponding flags everything work fine, but i want when country is selected country name and the flag as background picture to be displayed and i don't understand why my method can't set text a text it's make no sense for me.
this is my code: Note my "country" NSSTring is properly declared in interface and synthesized in .m
and namefieldText IBOutlet is connected.
Code:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    // report the selection to the UI label

   country = [customPickerArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];

      nameFiled.text =country;     // Nothing happens here

    NSLog(@"%@",country);         //NSLog show correctly selected country in a console 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your:

country = [customPickerArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];

Instead, you should be saying:

**country = [customPickerArray objectAtIndex:row];**

Good luck!